# How do I install mod_wsgi2.6 in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, python, django

I am having a problem while installing mod_wsgi 2.6 which supports Python 2.5 but I have Python 2.6 as the  default in Ubuntu.

Can you please tell me whether I have to find a mod_wsgi version supporting Python 2.6 or do I have to install Python 2.5 and set the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compile from source. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide

Use the '--with-python' option to 'configure' script for mod_wsgi to make it use non default Python installation.

Also see other documentation on mod_wsgi site as further steps may be required if that alternate Python installed in non standard location.